# Close and restart screen - ends up being duped!

Tags: bash, shell-script, ubuntu, gnu-screen

```
#!/bin/bash

set -o nounset
set -o errexit
trap 'echo "Aborting due to errexit on line $LINENO. Exit code: $?" >&2' ERR
set -o errtrace
set -o pipefail

SCR="bunny"
SCRIPT="/home/../run.sh" 



main() {
    if find_screen $SCR >/dev/null; then
        close_screen
        start_script
    fi
}

function start_script {
    echo "Starting script with new screen"
    screen -d -m -t $SCR sh $SCRIPT
}

function close_screen {
    if find_screen $SCR >/dev/null; then
        echo "Found! Deleting $SCR"
        screen -S -X $target_screen quit
    fi
}

function find_screen {
    if screen -ls "$1" | grep -o "^\s*[0-9]*\.$1[ "$'\t'"](" --color=NEVER -m 1 | grep -oh "[0-9]*\.$1" --color=NEVER -m 1 -q >/dev/null; then
        screen -ls "$1" | grep -o "^\s*[0-9]*\.$1[ "$'\t'"](" --color=NEVER -m 1 | grep -oh "[0-9]*\.$1" --color=NEVER -m 1 2>/dev/null
        return 0
    else
        echo "$1"
        return 1
    fi
}
target_screen=$(find_screen $SCR)
main "$@"
```

I am trying to create a script that restarts a specific screen. Now, the script does start the screen, but it also creates another screen with two dots `1234..randomName`.

The goal of the script is to:

- Check if screen exists
- If exists, close screen
- create a new screen session with `SCRIPT` name
- If it doesn't exist, create screen still!

Not sure what's going or why it isn't working. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Not related to the problem, but you should use standard shell function syntax instead of the `function` bashism.

Comment: To see what a script is doing, put `set -x` at the beginning. It will then show all the commands as it executes them. This should provide some insight about where `1234..randomName` is coming from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this to work with a few modifications:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -o nounset
# set -o errexit
# trap 'echo "Aborting due to errexit on line $LINENO. Exit code: $?" >&2' ERR
set -o errtrace
set -o pipefail

SCR="bunny"
SCRIPT="/home/../run.sh" 

function main() {
    if find_screen $SCR >/dev/null; then
        close_screen
        start_script
    fi
}

function start_script {
    echo "Starting script with new screen"
    screen -d -m -S $SCR sh $SCRIPT
}

function close_screen {
    if find_screen $SCR >/dev/null; then
        echo "Found! Deleting $SCR"
        screen -S $target_screen -X quit
    fi
}

function find_screen {

    result=$(screen -ls "$1" | grep -o "^\s*[0-9]*\.$1[ "$'\t'"](" --color=NEVER -m 1 | grep -oh "[0-9]*\.$1" --color=NEVER -m 1)

    if [ -z $result ]; then
      echo "$1"
      return 1
    else
        echo $result
        return 0
    fi
}
target_screen=$(find_screen $SCR)
main "$@"
```

- I commented out the following two lines:

```
       set -o errexit  
       trap 'echo "Aborting due to errexit on line $LINENO. Exit code: $?" >&2' ERR
```

These lines were interfering with your `return 1` statement in the `find_screen function`

- In the `close_screen` function, `screen -S -X $target_screen quit` needed slight modification: `screen -S $target_screen -X quit` to match the switches with the respective parameters.

The `if` statement in the `find_screen` function was never returning true, so I updated it slightly by adding a `results` variable, assigning it to your original test condition.  The resulting update is as follows:

```
    result=$(screen -ls "$1" | grep -o "^\s*[0-9]*\.$1[ "$'\t'"](" --color=NEVER -m 1 | grep -oh "[0-9]*\.$1" --color=NEVER -m 1)

    if [ -z $result ]; then
      echo "$1"
      return 1
    else
        echo $result
        return 0
    fi
```

***Other items***

- If you wish to name your screen based on the $SCR variable, you need to use the `-S` switch, as in

`screen -d -m -S $SCR`

... and add whatever other parameters and switches, as desired.

- In the `start_script` function, looks like you're trying to use the `-t` switch, instead of `-S`, in
  `screen -d -m -t $SCR sh $SCRIPT` - based on your description, "*create a new screen session with SCRIPT name*" you would use `-S` to set the screen session name.  You could combine this with `-t` to set the window name, as you may have multiple windows within a screen session: `screen -d -m -S $SCR -t`***`WindowName1`***

Comment: Hey just an update, while this works when doing ./start, when trying to use it with another script (let's say a nodejs app that runs this every minute) or a cronjob... it doesn't seem to work. The script outputs echo's from it, but that's it, no new screen is created.

Comment: Are you capturing any error messages when running the script from cronjob?